# 70s kids novel. Boy saved by "guardian devil" from accident

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult, childrens-novel, magical-creatures

Looking for a book from the 70's about a bratty kid who was always getting in trouble. One day while climbing a tree he falls out and is saved by his "guardian devil". He jokes that he will call this devil "Bub" for short and "Beelzebubbaroo" for long".

Comment: This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is [The Big Joke Game](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1503905.The_Big_Joke_Game) by Scott Corbett. For the record, it's not "Beelze**bubb**aroo", it's "Beelze**bub**aroo"

> A young boy who loves practical jokes and games finds himself in the
> strange land of Limbo where the only way out is to play a complicated
> game.

[image: Cover of "The Big Joke Game". Illustrated in a colorful, sketch-like style, a young boy falls through the air while a red devil watches him from a cliff. Several buildings on a green surface are visible behind him.]

Comment: Loved that book as a kid.

Comment: Thanks so much! Been trying to remember the title and author for a while. "For the record, it's not "Beelzebubbaroo", it's "Beelzebubaroo" "...I'm actually pretty amazed I got it that close considering I last read this book in the 70's. Thanks again!